# Probability to land in $(x,1)$ when adding i.i.d. uniform $(0,1)$ random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

You are playing the following game. You can ask the host of the game to tell you a number. Each number is an independent random uniformly distributed real number between 0 and 1. After the host tells you the number you can ask for more or just stop. When you stop, your score is equal to the sum of all numbers which the host has given to you. Let $0 < x < 1$ and suppose that you're trying to get a score in the interval from x to 1. What is the probability of winning, assuming that you are using the best possible strategy? Find the value of probability of winning for $x=0.334568$

Edit: so i ask my friend the complete problem. And re edit this to be more clear

First i use monte carlo method, but i have hard time to solve this riddle. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like blackjack!

Comment: What is the winning condition?  If I just ask for one number I will not exceed 1, which is the only way you have defined as losing.

Comment: @RossMillikan - Presumably the objective is to maximize the cumulative score, which resets to zero if it exceeds 1. But let's wait for OP's clarification.

Comment: @hypergeometric:  I would imagine that is correct, but then there is not a probability to win unless it is 1-the chance to go over 1.

Comment: @RossMillikan as long your score beetween 0 and 1, at first i think this is a silly game when you can always wining on this game, but my friend ask for spesific probability of a score.

Comment: We just had a question where A and B play this game.  A has to play first, then B tries to beat A without going over 1.  B has no strategic decision to make, but A has to have a threshold below which he draws and above which he stays.  You can then ask the threshold and what A's chance of winning is.  I can't find the problem right now.

Comment: @RossMillikan you play again the host. What ever your score is your winning condition. As i state above, you must get spesific winning condition of 0,334568.

Comment: The probability of a specific score is zero as you have to pick a specific real number to get that.  Unless you can ask a clear question, I vote to close this.

Comment: But $0.3+.1$ is still less than $1$. Why is the lose?

Comment: I think your explanation was sufficient before you edit your post. It is a clear game. You should maximize the sum, and the game is over if you pass $1$.

Comment: @RossMillikan i re edit my post to give more clear of the problem from the source, previously i post my intrepertation of the problem. So my apologize not give a clear question.

Comment: @msm i think that the case, when your score not get $0.3$ it mean youll loose, but since i cant solve this problem yet it's free for another perspective.

Comment: The new version does ask a clear question, so I will retract my close vote.  The strategy is simple, you just take numbers until you beat x.  Each time, if your current sum is $c$, you win outright with probability $1-x$, lose outright with probability $c$, and play again (with a new sum) with probability $x-c$.  The changing sum makes it not a simple geometric series problem.

Comment: The notion of "best possible strategy" is rather mysterious here: which strategy can there be, other than continuing to ask the host for new numbers while the sum of the numbers they already provided is less than $x$? Then either one sum falls in the interval $(x,1)$, one stops, and the game is won, or the sums jump directly from $(0,x)$ to $(1,\infty)$, and the game is lost. Mathematically speaking, one is given a sequence $(x_n)$ of i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and one asks for the probability of the event that there exists some $n$ ...

Comment: ... such that $x<x_1+\cdots+x_n<1$. To solve this, for every $y$, consider $w(y)$ the probability of the event $$\{\exists n\geqslant0,\,x<y+x_1+\cdots+x_n<1\}$$ Thus, $w(y)=1$ for $x<y<1$, $w(y)=0$ for $y>1$ and one is after the value of $w(0)$. Conditioning on $x_1$, one gets, for every $y$ in $(0,x)$, $$w(y)=\int_0^{x-y}w(y+z)dz+\int_{x-y}^{1-y}dz+\int_{1-y}^10dz=\int_y^xw(z)dz+1-x$$
To solve this integral identity, differentiate it to get $w'(y)=-w(y)$ hence $$w(y)=ce^{-y}$$ for every $y$ in $(0,x)$. Coming back to the integral identity, one gets ...

Comment: $$ce^{-y}=w(y)=\int_y^xw(z)dz+1-x=c(e^{-y}-e^{-x})+1-x$$ thus $$c=e^x(1-x)\qquad w(y)=e^{x-y}(1-x)$$ In particular, the probability to win is $$w(0)=e^x(1-x)$$

Comment: To compute the expected sum at the end of the game, one proceeds similarly. The expected sum $s(y)$ at the end of the game starting at $y$ solves $s(y)=0$ if $y>1$, $s(y)=y$ if $x<y<1$ and, for every $y$ in $(0,x)$, $$s(y)=\int_0^{x-y}s(y+z)dz+\int_{x-y}^{1-y}(y+z)dz+\int_{1-y}^10dz=\int_y^xs(z)dz+\frac{1-x^2}2$$ hence $s'(y)=-s(y)$ on $(0,x)$, $s(y)=Ce^{-y}$, and $$Ce^{-y}=C(e^{-y}-e^{-x})+\frac{1-x^2}2$$ that is, $$C=e^x\frac{1-x^2}2\qquad s(y)=e^{x-y}\frac{1-x^2}2$$ and finally the expected gain is $$s(0)=e^{x}\frac{1-x^2}2$$

Comment: @Did $w(0)=e^x(1-x)$ are the formula, thank you my friend has confirmed it.submit is as an answer!